# Bootstrap collapse expanding all cards when one is clicked

Tags: html, css, django, bootstrap-4, jinja2

Hi I am trying to use bootstrap collapse for a part of my django application.

This is my implementation so far:

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% block content %}
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-6">
            <div class="card">

                <h1 class="text-center">Recent reports</h1>

                <div class="accordion" id="accordionExample">

                    {% for report in reports %}

                    <div class="card">

                        <div class="card-header" id="report_{{ loop.counter }}">

                            <h2 class="mb-0">

                                {% if loop.counter == 1 %}

                                <button class="btn btn-link" type="button" data-toggle="collapse"
                                    data-target="#collapse{{ loop.counter }}" aria-expanded="true"
                                    aria-controls="collapse{{ loop.counter }}">

                                    Report #{{ report.report_number }}

                                </button>

                                {% else %}

                                <button class="btn btn-link collapsed" type="button" data-toggle="collapse"
                                    data-target="#collapse{{ loop.counter }}" aria-expanded="false"
                                    aria-controls="collapse{{ loop.counter }}">

                                    Report #{{ report.report_number }}

                                </button>

                                {% endif %}

                            </h2>

                        </div>

                        <div id="collapse{{ loop.counter }}" class="collapse"
                            aria-labelledby="report_{{ loop.counter }}" data-parent="#accordionExample">

                            <div class="card-body">

                                <table class="table">
                                    <tbody>
                                        <tr>
                                            <th scope="row">Date</th>
                                            <td>{{ report.datetime_submitted }}</td>
                                        </tr>
                                        <tr>
                                            <th scope="row">XYZ</th>
                                            <td>{{ report.xyz }}</td>
                                        </tr>
                                        .....
                                    </tbody>
                                </table>

                            </div>

                        </div>

                    </div>
                    {% endfor %}
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
{% endblock %}
```

I am facing an issue where when I click on the `card-header` card, **all** the collapse `card-body` class elements expand opposed to just the related one(which is the desired behaviour).

Any guidance on how to solve this will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rookie mistake:
I solved it by using `{{ forloop.counter }}` instead of `{{ loop.counter }}`.

Answer (score 0):

Use `{{loop.index}}` instead of `{{loop.counter}}`.

Comment: Thanks for your response @Ahmed Nuaman. I tried but it still behaves the same

Answer (score 0):

If you have your cards in a within a div with display:flex, this also seems to cause all the card-body classes to expand and collapse together. #itsafeature